# Generating .cabal file dependency versions

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I use Stack to build on my local machine, but Homebrew uses Cabal. This means that sometimes a build will work fine for me, but then not work in Homebrew. This seems to be because Cabal uses the *latest* packages, whereas Stack uses the ones from the resolver.

Is there a way to generate the package versions in the `.cabal` file automatically based on the current resolver? (I'm using a `package.yaml` file)

Comment: Checkout `stack sdist --pvp-bounds`: https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/09/stack-pvp

Comment: Hadn't thought of creating a tarball then extracting it to get the cabal file. That could work. My build script needs rewriting properly in any case. Not a perfect solution, but can probably get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

In FreeBSD Ports (which is alike Homebrew, AFAIK) we force `cabal` to use fixed versions of dependencies by fetching and unpacking them in the package directory and then calling `cabal new-build`. It also uses `hpack` to generate .cabal file from `package.yaml`. However, the dependencies list is generated manually by tweaking versions until the package builds successfully.